# Plotting a Plane from Equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have equations of the form x+y=4 and want to plot them in this way:
[image: Planes drawn by Hand]

I tried to use pgfplots and tikz, but didn't really succeed. With 2D plots its not problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look at the examples [here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need anything but basic Ti*k*Z for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[below]{$x_1$};
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[below]{$x_2$};
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[left]{$x_3$};
 \node[circle,draw,fill=black,label=below:$T_1$,scale=0.7] (b1) at (0,0,2){};
 \node[circle,draw,fill=black,label=below:$T_2$,scale=0.7] (b2) at (2,0,0){};
 \node[circle,draw,fill=black,label=right:$T_2$,scale=0.7] (b3) at (0,2,0){};
 \draw[thick,-] (b1) -- node[midway,below,sloped]{$g$ (Schnittgerade)} (b2) -- (b3) -- (b1);
 \fill[blue,opacity=0.2] (2,0,0) -- (0,0,2) -- (0,3,2) --  (2,3,0) -- node[midway,right]{$E$} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]